# How do I extract data which is the output of the block "log power FFT" in GNU Radio Companion?

Tags: python-2.7, gnuradio-companion

I am facing difficulty in converting complex float (output of log power FFT block) into complex (input of file sink) which is not available in type converters. But in order to execute the flow graph, it is necessary to convert.

I've tried to hear FM radio at 93.5 MHz and extract data of the same signal in binary form. My blocks are in the following order: osmocom source, remove dc spike autosync, log power fft, and file sink. I am unable to execute the flow graph if I directly connect the output of log power FFT block to the input of file sink block. The reason is mentioned above. It would help me if someone suggests a solution or a better way to get FFT output in the form of binary data.